# Git - Rename branch with pending PR's without breaking things

Tags: git, github

I have a fork of a repo which I have made commits to the master branch, then submitted a pull request which is still waiting for approval.

Now, as a git newb, I realize I should have done that in a branch, as I now want to do another change independent of the first change to do a separate PR.

I am wondering how I can rename master to another branch yet not break the pull request that is pending?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot change the source branch once you have created a PR. Note that you should not rename master. You should keep master so that you can keep up to date with any changes to the main repo. Instead, you will need to create a new branch for your changes and issue a new PR.

Answer (score -1):

You can create new branch based on parent commit of your PR using (assuming you have done one commit on your master branch)

```
git checkout -b branch_name HEAD^
```

Or your can use specific commit hash (do `git log --oneline` to find hash) as base of your new branch

```
git checkout -b branch_name commit_hash
```

This will create and checkout the new branch. You can use this new branch to create new PR request.

Comment: This wouldn't be the same PR